# get variable id in html string by jquery

Tags: jquery

I have html string

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="item_0122"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

item_0122(with 0122 is php variable)
with jquery I want get 0122 variable
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps

```
  var id = $("DIV").attr("id"); //item_0122
  var numPart = id.substring(5); //0122
```

or alternative

```
  var id = $("DIV").attr("id"); //item_0122
  var index = id.indexOf("_");  //index of _
  var numPart = id.substring(index + 1); //0122
```

Answer (score 0):

I Guess your looking for this...

```
var htmlString = "<html><body><div id=\"item_0122\">test</div></body></html>";
var res = htmlString.match(/item_\d+/g); 
var id= res[0].replace("item_","");
alert(id);
```

or else you can use same @jyrkim logic..

demo http://jsfiddle.net/RwX4G/

Comment: I have 3 <div> tag
<div id="1" class="bla"></div>

<div id="2" class="bla"></div>
<div id="3" class="bla"></div>
when click any tag I want alert id

Comment: Any way you can loop that `res` array object to get all elements id attribute value... for(var ele in res) { .... }. is it ok..?